# CSS fixed and percentage width with inner floats and centering

Tags: html, css

I have a responsive header which is quite complex.

The left block is fixed width and the right block is a percentage (100%) I found this great article here on how to do that except I need it the other way around, this example is right block fixed.

http://radiatingstar.com/make-a-layout-with-fluid-and-fixed-size-columns

I did get it working at one point but can't remember how I did it, there should be no scrollbar the outer container should be 100%. The real issue is that in the right block I have 2 inner divs, 1 div should be horizontally centered on the screen not centered in it's div as the fixed left block has pushed it over already.

http://jsfiddle.net/3519a9p0/1/

```
<div id="container">

    <div id=fixed-width>

    </div>

    <div id=fluid>

        <div class="farRight">right icons</div>    
        <div class="centeredBlock">centered on screen block</div>   

    </div>


</div>
```

And the other challenge is the responsive part in that the right icon block as you can see that that is floated to the right should move on top of the centered block as the screen width shrinks.

It would appear that I need to float the centered block too but then it needs to the centered middle of the screen too.

The the fixed width left block could potentially be a float too but it doesn't really matter as after the screen gets to small I switch to completely different layout, it's just the 2 inner divs that I need centered and responsive.

You're a genius if you can solve this!

Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

Here is a working example. I just got rid of the `margin` and the `float`. However, while the answer was simple, you should read on below to understand why this worked.

#### Working Example

Because the left `div` has a float: left attribute, you can just set the right div to take up 100% of the remaining space. You do not need the negative margin to work the div into its place.

Also, a `floated` element is taken out of the normal flow of the document, so now you can use `margin: 0 auto` and as long as the right div has 100% width, it will center across the entire screen.

### Update

There were post-question requests made via comments. To solve the issue, I added media queries and removed the float on the right-side div. Also, I had to add extra markup so that the inner divs on the right-hand side could be absolutely positioned properly.

Comment: This would be the one I need but the right black box should float on top of the red box, rather than the red box going into the left blue box

Comment: @user3468896 Then what do you want to happen with the blue box?

Comment: @user3468896 See updated answer. If that's not what you're looking for, could you try to explain what you want a bit more?

Comment: The blue box will stay as is, nothing should go into it, or happen to it. As the screen width shrinks the black box should float on top of the red box. I don't worry about screen widths that are to small as the whole layout will change anyway. But the width of the red and black box will be greater than the screen width can provide on one line at a certain width so they should sit vertically with each other

Comment: @user3468896 See updated link, it will do what you want it to do. You can play around with the screen size too

Comment: @user3468896 If this does what you want, could you mark the answer as accepted? If not, let me know what's missing. I'm trying to close the question

Answer (score 1):

Here is revised CSS. The major changes are:

- No need to float the fluid column, add left margin instead
- To center a box on the screen, set relative positioning on the container (not the fluid box) and use absolute positioning on the box

As for responsiveness, you can simply remove float, width, height and positioning from elements so that they appear as rows.

```css
/* body margin/padding is reset to get media queries right */
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#container {
  position: relative;
  height: 100px;
}
#fixed-width {
  float: left;
  width: 250px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
}
#fluid {
  margin-left: 250px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: green;
}
.farRight {
  float: right;
  width: 100px;
  height: 40px;
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
}
.centeredBlock {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 200px;
  height: 40px;
  color: white;
  background-color: tomato;
}
/* when screen is narrower than 250+200+250 pixels trigger breakpoint 1 */
@media screen and (max-width: 699px) {
  .farRight {
    float: none;
    width: auto;
  }
  .centeredBlock {
    position: static;
    width: auto;
  }
}
/* when screen is narrower than whatever-you-want pixels trigger breakpoint 2 */
@media screen and (max-width: 499px) {
  #container {
    height: auto;
  }
  #fixed-width {
    float: none;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
  }
  #fluid {
    margin-left: 0;
    height: auto;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="fixed-width">fixed width</div>
  <div id="fluid">
    <div class="farRight">right icons</div>
    <div class="centeredBlock">centered on screen block</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks the layout works well! However when shrinking the screen I need the right icons the black box to float on top of the red box. As it is now the red box will float into the blue left box which it shouldn't

Comment: OK, the blue box needs at least 700px screen (250px left margin + 200px width + 250px right margin) or it will run into the blue box. I have added a breakpoint for 700px screens and another one (as an example) for even smaller screens.